# How do I create a dataset in SQL Server and process each record?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[proposalReviewAction]
(
    [proposalReviewActionID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [proposalPackageID] [INT] NULL,
    [approvalTypeID] [INT] NULL,
    [comments] [VARCHAR](2000) NULL,
    [reviewedByID] [INT] NULL,
    [reviewedDate] [DATETIME] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

I want to return each record that has an `approvalTypeID = 100` and use the `proposalPackageID` in another process that moves the data from the proposal table to the project table.

I considered using a `WHILE` loop, but everyone seems to favor processing a dataset but I cannot find any way to do this in SQL/T-SQL.

I found an example of a `WHILE` loops and modified it ...

```
WHILE (SELECT[approvalTypeID] FROM [proposalReviewAction]) = 100
BEGIN  
    DECLARE @ppID AS INT ;

    SELECT [proposalPackageID] AS ppID, [approvalTypeID] AS atID 
    FROM [proposalReviewAction]

    IF (SELECT [approvalTypeID] AS atID FROM [proposalReviewAction]) = 100
        PRINT @ppID
    ELSE
        BREAK
END  

PRINT 'I got to the print statement';
```

... but I get the following error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Then, it prints the "PRINT" statement.

Any help is appreciated...

Bob

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. Your subquery returns more than 1 row and you trying to see if equals 100. How that can be evaluated if there are multiple rows? I have to agree that doing this in a loop is a poor way to do whatever it is you are doing. Sql should be done set based, not RBAR (row by agonizing row).

Comment: @SeanLange, what alternative would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest a set based approach. Forget the loop unless you really need it. You say something about processing the row but that is unclear what that means.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to do with the `ppID` values?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn, the ppID value will correspond to the proposalPackageID in the proposal table.  I want to use the ppID to pull the data from the proposal table and insert it into the project table.  I only want to process the proposal records with an approvalTypeID = 100 (which represents an "approval to fund."

Comment: @SeanLange, is there a way to do this in a 'set based approach' within SSMS or TSQL?  If so, can you provide an example?

Comment: so, I found another option (a cursor)
DECLARE /@ppID as int;
DECLARE Proposal_Cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT [proposalPackageID] as ppID, [approvalTypeID] as atID 
FROM [proposalReviewAction]  
WHERE [approvalTypeID] = 100
OPEN Proposal_Cursor;  
FETCH NEXT FROM Proposal_Cursor;  
WHILE /@/@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
   BEGIN  
      FETCH NEXT FROM Proposal_Cursor; 
   END;  
CLOSE Proposal_Cursor;  
DEALLOCATE Proposal_Cursor;  
GO  

This provides the correct records but the normal way of assigning to a variable doesn't work
/@ppID = ppID

Comment: Have a look at using a CTE or subquery to get the filtered data you want. You can also put ID's into a temporary table for another process to use as the basis of work

Comment: A cursor is just another way of doing a loop. For the third time (from me) what are you doing in the loop? That is the important part here.

Comment: @SeanLange, as I've stated multiple times, I want to insert a call to a process that takes the data from the proposal table and inserts selected fields into a project table.  THAT process is working but only processes records ONE AT A TIME.  I'm trying to automate the process by looping through the records with the proper approvalType and processing them all at once instead of running the individual process 400 times...

Comment: Then change the process so it can handle a set instead of RBAR. But at the very least if you only want to process rows where approvalTypeID = 100 you should add a where clause to the first select so you only get rows you want to process instead of looking at rows you don't care about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply insert these records **directly** to your `ProjectTable`! like:

```
INSERT INTO [ProjectTable] (...)
SELECT proposalPackageID 
FROM [proposalReviewAction]
WHERE approvalTypeID  = 100
```

If you need a **loop** anyway for other reasons you can use a **cursor** instead of a `WHILE`. Using a **cursor** helps you have results of a query in variables record by record and process each record separately :

```
DECLARE @proposalPackageID INT

DECLARE product_cursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT proposalPackageID 
    FROM dbo.proposalReviewAction 
    WHERE approvalTypeID = 100

OPEN product_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @proposalPackageID
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

  -- Insert directly into projectTable or call external process  
  INSERT INTO [projectTable] (proposalPackageID ...)
  SELECT @proposalPackageID


  FETCH NEXT FROM product_cursor INTO @proposalPackageID 
END  
CLOSE product_cursor  
DEALLOCATE product_cursor
```

Hope this will help

Comment: Thanks, this works...
I tried to use the cursor (I added my cursor to a comment above) but I was missing the "INTO" statement in the FETCH.

Answer (score 1):

Given this table:

```
   CREATE TABLE [dbo].[proposalReviewAction]
    (
        [proposalReviewActionID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
        [proposalPackageID] [INT] NULL,
        [approvalTypeID] [INT] NULL,
        [comments] [VARCHAR](2000) NULL,
        [reviewedByID] [INT] NULL,
        [reviewedDate] [DATETIME] NULL
    ) ON [PRIMARY]
```

You can select all records with `approvalTypeID = 100` by using a simple SELECT statement

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.proposalReviewAction WHERE approvalTypeID = 100;
```

If you only need `proposalPackageID` then you can SELECT just it using the QUERY

```
SELECT proposalPackageID FROM dbo.proposalReviewAction WHERE approvalTypeID = 100;
```

Depending on the processing you could insert directly from here to the 'project table' as well

```
INSERT INTO [projectTable] (proposalPackageID ...)
SELECT proposalPackageID, ...
FROM dbo.proposalReviewAction WHERE approvalTypeID = 100;
```

Comment: I think you missed the part where I said, "I want to return each record that has an approvalTypeID = 100 and use the proposalPackageID in another process that moves the data from the proposal table to the project table."

I've got the list, I just need to loop through and process each record.

Comment: This is returned as a list and then you can do whatever you want with them indivually or on whole. You also need to state what kind of processing you want to do for more explicit help. Cursors and WHILE loops are expensive in a DB and depending on the processing, you may need to do that in the application. There is a reason people favor set-based processing in a DB.

Answer (score 0):

```
select column 
from table 
where columns_name 
  in ( select column from table where columns_name = 'value');
```

NOTE: If we use sub query and it return one value in this case we can use (=,!=,<>,<,>....)
Or more than one values, in this case we should use (in,any,all,some )